# PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE html5 video android

Tags: html, video

Html5 video does not work in chrome on android 4.1, all checks was successful:
"('' MediaSource 'in window)"
"MediaSource.isTypeSupported (codec)".

I 'm trying to play MediaSource video in the browser, and it working in desktop browsers versions, it works on Android 4.4, so I see that my video should be supported even on android 2.3 [android media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html).

Could you tell me how can I solve this problem?

Video codec - "video / mp4; codecs =" avc1.4D001F "".
Error - "PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: video decoder reinitialization failed".